# Is natural gas transported as a liquid or supercritical fluid?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, gas

is natural gas transported as a liquid or supercritical fluid?
I am curious as to what phase natural gas is in when being transported in pipelines over long distances. Both liquid and supercritical fluid phases seem to have their own set of unique difficulties involving temperature pressure and feasibility of use. Which is preferred and why?

Comment: In pipelines it is a gas. LNG ships are a different thing…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In industrial applications, natural gas is sent through pipelines at ambient temperature and pressures somewhat higher than ambient pressure.  Thus, it is transported through pipelines as a gas.  Note that ambient temperatures are higher than the critical temperature of natural gas, indicating that for this application, natural gas is indeed transported as a "supercritical fluid".

When shipped overseas, natural gas is liquified at low temperature in order to maximize its density such that the maximum mass of natural gas can be placed in the constant volume tanks of the LNG ship.

Regarding which is preferred, it takes a lot of energy to liquify natural gas, and a LOT of insulation on long pipelines to keep it liquid.  Since the natural gas must be in the gaseous state to use it as a fuel (its normal use), it is not economic or desirable to attempt to send natural gas through pipelines as a liquid.